# Conditional formatting with formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I am looking at using a formula based conditional formatting but can't seem to get it to work.

What I am after is:

Its a roster, with variables in it

- IF A2 Contains say 0:00 or 0:30 or 13:30 and so on, then input conditional formatting is activated - i.e. Cell A17 goes red or what ever colour I have chosen for it.
- IF A1 Contains RDO, AL or PH, then input conditional formatting is activated - i.e. Cell A17 goes red or what ever colour I have chosen for it.
- If cell has no text and is blank do not input conditional formatting. I am placing this conditional formatting on say Cell A17 to reflect what is inputted on cell A2.

I've tried doing multiple formulas with 0:00 and RDO separate, but they don't work.

```
=A2="RDO" 
=A2="0:00"
```

[image]

Comment: You simply want an OR? If A2 is RDO OR 0:00 then A17 is red?